# I am trying to filter ascending, descending, old price promotional-price to be shown in the public page

Tags: python, django, filter

```
if request.GET.get("sort", False):
    category_products = category_products.filter(old_price=request.GET.get("sort"))
```

Comment: What do you try to do, what are the models you use? What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to [**`.order_by(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) the value:

```
    chosen_genders = request.GET.getlist("gender", False)
    if chosen_genders:
        category_products = category_products.filter(gender__in=chosen_genders)
    if request.GET.get('sort') in ('old_price', '-old_price', 'title', '-title'):
        category_products = category_products.order_by(request.GET['sort'])
```

I strongly advise to check if the value is in a list of values, since ordering by an arbitrary field can result in exposing data you do not want to expose: a hacker could use binary search to determine the value of a field.